# Square-free Mersenne numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, square-free

Questions about prime numbers are notoriously hard. Let me ask one which may be easier:

**QUESTION**:  are there infinitely many square-free Mersenne numbers

$$ M(n)\ := 2^n-1 $$

where $\ n\in\mathbb N\ $ are arbitrary natural numbers (*not necessarily prime*)?

===============================================

===============================================

I am interested in *baroque numbers* $\ n,\ $ where $\ n\ $ is an $b$-baroque ($b\in\mathbb N)\ <=:=>\ S(n)/n=b\ $ and $\ S(n)\ $ is the sum of the divisors of $\ n.$

Of course, 2-baroque numbers are the same as perfect numbers.

We see that $\ s(n):=S(n)/n\ $ is a product of fractions of the form $\ s(p^t)/p^t $ for certain prime numbers $\ p\ $ (since $\ s\ $ is a multiplicative function). These fractions have to cancel out to result in $\ b.\ $

Since

$$ S(p^t)\ =\ \sum_{k=0}^t p^k $$

I am interested in the prime decomposition of such geometric series. The special case of $\ p=2\ $ is related to the above **QUESTION**:

$$ M(n)\ =\ S(2^{n-1}) $$

(All this, so far, is very elementary but... messy).

PS. I could ask about all $\ S(p^{n-1})\ $ but it goes without saying -- it's simpler to ask a simpler question.

Comment: FYI, this [answer](/a/150252) of a closely related question [Density of all n such that 2^n-1 is square free](/q/150247) states "... we don't know if there exist infinitely many squarefree numbers of the form $2^n-1$". I believe you'll find the other answers there also of interest. Finally, there's the somewhat related [Squarefree Parts of Mersenne Numbers](/q/149511) that you may find of some use.

Comment: It is expected that $2^n - 1$ should be squarefree for prime $n$, but this is still open.  A repeated prime factor must be a Wieferich prime (to base $2$), and the only known such primes, 1093 and 3511, can't occur as repeated prime factors of $2^n-1$ for prime $n$. See L. J. Warren and H. G. Bray, "On the square-freeness of Fermat and Mersenne numbers" Pacific J. Math 22 (1967), 563-564. It's available online at https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-22/issue-3/On-the-square-freeness-of-Fermat-and-Mersenne-numbers/pjm/1102992105.pdf

Comment: @JohnOmielan & KConrad, thank you for your comments. I'm interested in this and more general q's because of what I call baroque numbers (*multiply perfect*).

Comment: @JohnOmielan, I have followed your suggestions (please, see the post above).

Comment: @JohnOmielan, I've fixed that type (and have added a PS).